# Promise don't resolve in catchError typescript

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, ionic4, resolve

I need resolve(false) in catchError, but this dosn't work.

**In my loin.page.ts**

```js
async login() {
      if (this.signin.valid) {
        const controls = this.signin.controls;
        const valid = await this.authService.signin(controls.email.value, controls.password.value);
        if (valid) {
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/user', { animated: true});
        } else {
            console.log('Bad credentials');
        }
    }
  }
```

**authService.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

signin(email, password) {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        });
        const data = {
            email,
            password
        };
        const url = URL_SERVICIOS + 'xxx';
        return new Promise ((resolve) => {

            this.http.post(url, data).pipe(
                map( (result: any) => {
                    this.credentials = result;
                    resolve(true);
                }),
                catchError(() => {
                    return Promise.resolve(false);
                })
            ).subscribe();
        });
     }
```

This code ends in *'return Promise.resolve(false);'* and does not continue in *loin.page.ts*

Comment: instead of `pipe`, don't you want `then`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try like below, just annotated with type and used resolve() in both success and catch block

```
...
 return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
     this.http.post(url, data).pipe(
         map( (result: any) => {
             this.credentials = result;
             resolve(true);
         }),
         catchError(() => {
             resolve(false);
         })
         ).subscribe();
     });
...
```

Comment: I get this error
Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<void>) => ObservableInput<any>'.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are returning a new Promise which will resolve instead of calling the resolve callback.

Try to do:

```
        catchError(() => {
             resolve(false);
         })
```

Comment: i get Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<void>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Comment: could you post the whole function that returns the promise?

Comment: ah okay. Its because the signature of the function you are passing to catchError is wrong: try this:   catchError((error) => {resolve(false); return error});

Comment: In console
ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.